# Lambda with auto type within collection sorting argument

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, collections, set

This is an example of a simplified problem that I try to resolve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

auto comp = [](int x, int y) { return x < y; };

struct Struct {
    set<int, decltype(comp)> member(comp);
};

int main() {
    Struct variable;
    variable.member.insert(1);
    variable.member.insert(5);

    for(auto v: variable.member) {
            cout << v << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using the following command to compile my code:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -o test.exe test.cpp
```

Unfortunately, it keeps producing following error:

```
test.cpp:9:34: error: unknown type name 'comp'
set<int, decltype(comp)> reads(comp);
                               ^
```

I have tried to install newer version of g++, but it doesn't work.
I executed this command on MacOS with Clang, as well as Ubuntu 16 with g++ in version 5.2.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example one can use to reproduce the error? The snippet above isn't enough.

Comment: Not sure what your intent is here. Can you expand on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am willing to have some own compare function. That will allow me to iterate through elements in desired order.

Comment: Compiler may be confusing a data member definition with a member function declaration. Help it by replacing the initialiser with a curly bracket format and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Struct {
  set<int, decltype(comp)> member{ comp };
};
```

My visual studio 2017 complains that 'comp' is not a type name and it can not see the definition of 'member', so I guess the compiler recognizes 'member' as a function definition.

Use `member{ comp }` seems solves this problem

Answer (score 1):

Without structure this example can be compiled as:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

auto& comp = [](int x, int y){ return x < y; };

auto member = set<int, decltype(comp)>(comp);

int main() {
    member.insert(1);
    member.insert(5);

    for (auto v : member) {
        cout << v << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For case with structure, try:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

auto& comp = [](int x, int y){ return x < y; };

struct Struct {
    set<int, decltype(comp)> member = set<int, decltype(comp)>(comp);
} variable;

int main() {
    variable.member.insert(1);
    variable.member.insert(5);

    for (auto v : variable.member) {
        cout << v << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My Visual Studio 2013 cannot compile `auto member = set<int, decltype(comp)>(comp);` insude structure - error is `error C2853: 'member' : a non-static data member cannot have a type that contains 'auto'`

Comment: Without structure, it works even without reference (&).
However struct/class is crucial for my usage.

Comment: @ArturLaskowski Updated